# Break for loop in an if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, break

Currently having trouble with breaking this `for` loop. I want to break it if the variable is not found in this list so it can move two another `for` loop. It expects an indented block for the top of the `for` loop, but if I change the position of the `break` or of the start of the `for` loop, it doesn't work. Help!

```
while cyclenumb <= 10000:

    for x in userpassword[k]:
        for z in lowercaselist:
            if x in z:
                newpasswordlist.append(z)
                k +=1
                break
        else:

    for x in userpassword[k]:
        for z in uppercaselist:
            if x in z:
                newpasswordlist.append(z)
                k +=1
                break
        else:
```

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the inner loop, not the outer loop. Are you sure you need the inner loops? Maybe it should just be `if x in lowercaselist`

Comment: At first glance, your indentation seems incorrect. Does the first else go against the first if x in z? Then it should be indented to the same level as the first if. Does the third for statement go under that else? Then everything should be indented one level deeper than the else.

Comment: What's the value of `lowercaselist` and `uppercaselist`? Are they lists of lists? That's whay it looks like when you're looping over them and then using `x in z`.

Comment: barmar, they are lists containing the lower and upper cases of the alphabet, ex "a", "b",

Comment: Then why are you using `x in z` instead of just `x = z`? Or why don't you just write `if x in lowercaselist:`?

Comment: that'll work, how am i supposed to append that value?? to a new list

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to break out of each loop separately, as people have mentioned in the comments for your question, `break` only stops the loop which it's in

```
for x in userpassword[k]:
    for z in lowercaselist:
        if x in z:
            newpasswordlist.append(z)
            k +=1
            break
    if x in z: # added an extra condition to exit the main loop
        break
```

You'll need to do this for **both** loops. If you want to break out of the while loop as well, then you can add `if x in z: break` in that loop as well.

Comment: Yeah, that means the index is too big for the list, for example if you have a `list` of 4 elements, and you try to get `list[5]` it will give an error because there is no 5th element

Comment: thank you, i was able to troubleshoot the index problem, but now, after i added the print newpasswordlist function after the last k+=1 n the if statement, it prints the value of z twice

Comment: thank you sir, i will add this too my multiple other for loops in my program, hopefully it will work