# Magic Number in Python

Tags: python

In the following code :

```
magicnumber = 256
for n in range (500):
    if n is magicnumber:
        print ("the magic number is " , n)
        break
    else:
        print(n)
```

The loop breaks at 256, but if you set `magicnumber` to 257, it doesn't. Why ?

Comment: because your code calls `break` after n = 256...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41065354/2573061

Comment: OK run the code below and the return value will be zero     magicnumber = 257
for n in range (500):
    if n is magicnumber:
        print ("the magic number is " , n)

Comment: `n is magicnumber` -> `n == magicnumber` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers))

Comment: Your answer is correct but can you explain it to me what is the difference between is and equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are checking for `identity` with `is` (instead of checking for `equality` with `==`).

As an implementation detail, Python keeps an array of integer objects for all integers
between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get
back a reference to the existing object.

So integers above 256 will still be `equal`, but not `identical` (unless they refer to the same object, you can compare that with `id()`).

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong