# how do I break a loop

Tags: python, while-loop

when you answer m[0] or m[1] it's supposed to break the x and y loop but it just keeps on asking me the same questions. Anyone who can help me?

```
while y == True:
   B=input("Klockan är 07:00 och du börjar snart, vad för slags frukost skulle du vilja ha? smörgås, omellett eller pannkakor: ")
   if B == 'smörgås': 
     y=False
     x=True`enter code here`
     while x == True:
       C=input("Du valde smörgås och därför skulle jag rekommendera juice eller mjölk, 
              vad vill du ha?")
       if C == m[0]:
         print ("ok, ha en trivlig måltid")
         x = False
       if C == m[1]:
         print ("ok ha en trevlig måltid")
         x=False
       else:  
         print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken drick du vill ha eller så har du använt 
                 stora bokstäver, var vänlig att svara igen")
         x=True
```

Comment: What is `m`?  Note that `input` returns a string, so `m[0]` and `m[1]` need to be strings as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking out of loop - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071998/breaking-out-of-loop-python)

Answer (score 1):

use a `break` statement
error is occurring because last else statement makes x `True` again. [your indentation is wrong correct it by yourself]

```py
while y:
   B=input("Klockan är 07:00 och du börjar snart, vad för slags frukost skulle du vilja ha? smörgås, omellett eller pannkakor: ")
   if B == 'smörgås': 
     y=False
     x=True
     while x:
       C=input("Du valde smörgås och därför skulle jag rekommendera juice eller mjölk, 
              vad vill du ha?")
       if C == m[0]:
         print ("ok, ha en trivlig måltid")
         x = False
         break
       if C == m[1]:
         print ("ok ha en trevlig måltid")
         x=False
         break
       else:  
         print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken drick du vill ha eller så har du använt 
                 stora bokstäver, var vänlig att svara igen")
         x=True
```